# Avoid going to String first when gzipping

Tags: kotlin, stream, gzip

Is there a way of doing this gzip without first going to String and then back to ByteArray?

```
suspend fun gzip(content: ByteArray): ByteArray = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream().apply {
        GZIPOutputStream(this).writer(UTF_8).use { it.write(String(content)) }
    }.toByteArray()
}

suspend fun ungzip(content: ByteArray): ByteArray = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    GZIPInputStream(content.inputStream()).bufferedReader(UTF_8).use { it.readText() }.toByteArray()
}
```

Comment: How exactly do you observe it is truncated? I think this is the proper solution. Try to close `GZIPOutputStream` after write - you can use `use()` similarly as in your code above. Writers/readers are for strings, you shouldn't use them here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you close the `GZIPOutputStream` before consuming it via `toByteArray()`. When correctly closed the buffer will be written onto the output stream and no truncated data is present.

```kotlin
suspend fun gzip(content: ByteArray): ByteArray = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream().apply {
        GZIPOutputStream(this)
           .write(content)
           .close()
    }.toByteArray()
}
```

You can then consume your data via

```kotlin
suspend fun ungzip(content: ByteArray) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
  GZIPInputStream(zipped.inputStream()).readAllBytes()
}
```